# Fitness assessments

Tags: body-measurements, measurements, assesment

I would like to do all kind of fitness related assessments that are not to difficult/costly.

They should produce reports that can be understood by similar professionals.  Ideally it should be possible to repeat them and compare the status.

I am thinking broadly, like balance, flexibility, core.

I am not looking so much for specific measurements, but assessments that I can ask Physiotherapists and other professionals to do for me, and have some kind of output.

The objective is to know what to ask for, when I talk to professionals.

Comment: Could you make the question more specific? At the moment you are basically asking for a list of things, which is [bad in general](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139623/176874). It would be much better if you'd split the question into several separate ones. Especially because some of the ways to measure certain aspects of the body have already received good answers here and don't need to be asked again.

Comment: Possible duplicate (but more specific): http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/3421/3941

Comment: I am interested in measurements, but my questions is more complementary in that i am looking for assessments, not just single measurements.

Comment: Hi! I gave an answer, but didn't address "core", because I don't think it's an area of fitness. It contributes to the others though. Improved core strength will increase your balance, agility, ability to display power... maybe more!

Comment: Your question says "I am not looking so much for specific measurements", but your comment says "I am interested in measurements". What did you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "assessments that I can ask professionals to do for me"? Do you mean, instead of running 40 yards on your own, you want to ask a professional to ask you to run 40 yards?

Comment: I am interested in measurements, but this question is about broader assessments :-)

Comment: In the case of aerobic fitness, the best would perhaps to pick single measurements, and get a pro do do them for me.  But also there it could for example be best to have a combination of measurements, and I might be more interested in aggregated results than single measurements.  Also if the tests are not standard, it can be difficult to repeat them.

Comment: The single measurement you're looking for is your VO2Max, but that's a very expensive test and needs specialized equipment. Just run the beep test. It is very correlated with VO2Max.

Comment: In case of flexibility I don't know exactly what to measure, and it would not make much sense to ask a physiotherapist "can yo do this".  One thing is that they are specialized, and I would not know what kind of physiotherapist to look for.

Comment: In case of flexibility I don't know exactly what to measure, and it would not make much sense to ask a physiotherapist "can yo do these measurements". One thing is that they are specialized, and I would not know what kind of physiotherapist to look for.  Also, when it comes to stiff muscles for example, you can't make a numerical measurements, but there must be standard methods to assess it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some things you can do (I'm just making this up on the spot, based on somebody else's breakdown of the 10 areas of fitness, but they're things I've done in the past or currently to track my progress). They are mostly very standard ways to test these things and understood by any professional you'll visit.

**Cardiovascular/respiratory endurance**

Do the [beep test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_fitness_test). It's a good proxy for your VO2Max. All you need is to download the mp3.

**Stamina**

How fast do you run 5km, or 10km?

**Strength**

What is your max back squat? bench press? overhead press?

**Flexibility**

Huge list of tests here: http://www.exrx.net/Lists/Tests.html

**Power**

How much can you power clean? Or, what is your vertical jump from a standstill? You can test this one by marking on a wall the highest spot you can touch while both feet are still planted on the ground. Then jump up as high as you can and mark the highest spot you can reach. The difference between the two is your "standing vertical jump" and is basically only improved by improving your power.

**Speed**

What is your 40 yard dash time?

**Coordination**

I can't think of a test for this one. Maybe something like bouncing a tennis ball off a wall and back to yourself (barehanded). Do this at a difficult distance. See how many times you can do this without dropping it.

**Agility**

The [NFL combine](http://www.nfl.com/combine/workouts)'s 3-cone drill and shuttle run are good agility tests:

> The 3 cone drill tests an athlete's ability to change directions at a
>   high speed. Three cones in an L-shape. He starts from the starting
>   line, goes 5 yards to the first cone and back. Then, he turns, runs
>   around the second cone, runs a weave around the third cone, which is
>   the high point of the L, changes directions, comes back around that
>   second cone and finishes.
>
> The short shuttle is the first of the cone drills. It is known as the
>   5-10-5. What it tests is the athlete's lateral quickness and explosion
>   in short areas. The athlete starts in the three-point stance, explodse
>   out 5 yards to his right, touches the line, goes back 10 yards to his
>   left, left hand touches the line, pivot, and he turns 5 more yards and
>   finishes.

**Balance**

There are a couple of ways to approach this. Do you want to test balance that you've acquired as a skill? Like standing one-legged on a balance board? Or do you want to see how your general training has helped you with balance in general? This is trickier... you'd have to see things like "am I rolling my ankles less while hiking", or "am I injured less during sports". But, since you want something repeatable, you could do a test like how long can you stand on a balance board, how long can you do it with one leg, with eyes closed, while moving your other leg to other points in space around the board, etc. But, don't practice whatever balance test you'll be doing other than in the tests, otherwise you'll just be testing a skill rather than your general balance ability.

**Accuracy**

This depends on what type of accuracy you want to test. Are you a thrower? Are you a volleyball setter? Are you a basketball shooter? Are you a hunter that shoots? You can pick whatever type of accuracy you would like to test and basically do what you'd do in the range with a gun to test your accuracy.

Throw a ball at a target on a wall. How close did you get? Repeat this 10 times and take the total. Or,

How many baskets do you make from 10 points around the key? Or,

What is your score at the shooting range? (This should be improved by improving your fitness!)

**What you'll have**

You might do this over a weekend once every 4 months or so, and get a results that look like this:

- Beep test: 8.5
- 5k: 20:56
- Squat: 200lbs, Bench: 100lbs, Overhead press: 70lbs
- [Open hand shoulder mobility test](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/FlexFunction/ShoulderMobilityOpen.html): -0.5 inch, [Sit and reach flexibility test](http://www.exrx.net/Calculators/SitReach.html): 14 inches
- Vertical jump: 24 inches
- 40 yard dash: 6.2 seconds
- Coordination: 42 bounce+catches
- Shuttle run: 7.3 seconds
- Time 1-legged on a balance board with eyes closed: 35 seconds
- Accuracy: 95 (I don't know... some accuracy score, depending on what you do)

Then, you should make each of these numbers better for the next time you test, or you can bring them to a fitness professional and tell them which ones you want to improve in the next few months, and they can give you a program to suit that goal.