# Is 5 to 6 times workout per Week too much for the muscles to recover?

Tags: workout-routines, gym, bellyfat, boxing

After my time in the army (5 Months), i gained 6kg. My eating habits got lost and I ate everything and to any time. Now I gained alot of belly-fat, but when i look at the rest of my body i don't look that wispy anymore.. Now I continue with my Kickbox Workout again (3x per Week). 1x we have endurance and stamina training and 2x basic Kickbox technics..

Now i wanted to start with fitness in the gym on my other free days except for one day on the weekend. I want to do some weight lifting to gain some muscles. Is this too much for my Muscles to regenerate or would it be ok?

The plan would look like this:

- Monday: Kickboxing (soon some sparring) 50 Minutes
- Tuesday: Gym
- Wendsday: Kickboxing endurance and stamina
- Thursday: Gym
- Friday: Basic Kickbox training 80 Minutes
- Saturday: Gym
- Sunday: Free

My friend from kickboxing said it would be too much for body. But I want to get in shape as fast as possible. It's already april damnit.. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the kind of exercises you're doing in the endurance and stamina kickboxing sessions? My gut instinct is to say that yes, that's far too much to recover properly, but it depends on the duration and intensity of your sessions and which muscle groups you're working, among other things.

Comment: Also, I can appreciate and sympathise with wanting to lose the fat quickly, but trying to rush it is probably going to do more harm than good. If you're constantly exhausted and sore from exercising you're less likely to want to do it, and therefore more likely to stop doing it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist In the endurance and stamina workout we are always taking a kickbox technic e.g. "block, punch, chap, roundhousekick" then it's like 2minutes doing this. 1 minute push ups (or other exercises) 2 minutes same technic with laying on the ground & standing up between technics, 1 minute break then doing everything from the begin. this is the most exhausting part of the kickbox training. the friday and the monday mostly aren't that hard. after those workouts i always feel like i could jogg for an hour after this.

Comment: Probably should have asked this to begin with, but do you have any plans for a workout schedule in your gym sessions yet? Knowing what you're planning on doing will help people decide if you're going to risk overtraining or not giving your body time to recover.

Comment: Well actually I have my first appointement on thursday. I still don't know what kind of workout shedule the guy at the gym will make for me... or what excactly is waiting for me at the gym. it's my first time going to the gym.

Comment: and additionally, I have an office job, so my whole day isn't physically exhausting at all.

Comment: It sounds like the planned schedule will put too much stress on your body, there is no time for recovery. Will probably feel ok for 2-3 weeks but then the probability for overtraining or injuries will increase. Perhaps this QA can help you, see http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/9950/3778

Comment: how long is your usual kickboxing training?

Comment: the sessions on monday and wendsday are 50 minutes the session on friday is 1 hour and 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No workout schedule is intrinsically too much. This schedule might be too much *for you*, just as it may be entirely doable for an elite-level heavyweight kickboxer.

If you've been kickboxing three times a week for several months and you're feeling great, then adding one to three lifting workouts might be fine. If you just started kickboxing, or if you already feel exhausted from the current workload, then adding three lifting workouts to your existing three kickboxing workouts will probably end in overtraining, injury, or noncompliance.

I'd stick with one or two lifting sessions per week at first, and only ramp up to three once you're sure that it's been working for a while.

Comment: Yesterday i went for the first time, and my trainer told me that i should do strenght/weight training on saturday (after an easy kickbox session) and explosive strenght training (i hope its correct in english) on tuesdays. So i will try this for a while and if i can i will stack up to 3 sessions per week.

Comment: @Aytac That sounds like a good plan for strength and kickboxing. (Also, your english is quite good.)

Answer (score 1):

Your scheme shouldn't just say "Gym". You should make a plan of which muscle groups to work on.

As the answer from @DaveLiepmann says, your training might be too much for *you*, but it might also be *fine* for you. That depends on your shape - that is, it depends on how fit your body is right now and how well (how fast) it recovers.
http://www.corerunning.com/recovery.html

Usually a rule of thumb I have heard is to have two days of pause between workouts of *the same muscle group* for most people in usual condition. And after some time you can extend your training to just one day of pause between workouts.
Feel for yourself, when the sore is almost away again. At that time you are ready again.

But keep in mind that this is a rule regarding each muscle group individually. You can without any hesitation start training other parts of your body (of course your endurance (hearts and lungs) is also to consider as a group to train) without any pauses. If you can make a schedule of kickboxing as now, and fill in the inbetween days with gym training of other muscle groups, then that's preferable.

Although I suspect kickboxing to be full body exercise... Then it can be difficult to find unexhausted muscles to work on in the gym. You've got to feel for yourself how ready you are when standing in the gym.