# how to measure my total fitness?

Tags: strength, muscle, assessment, app

is there any way to measure my total fitness, like muscular strength, muscular endurance, cardiovascular endurance, flexibility, and body fat composition.

I mean an app or website to get my data (weight, height, BMI, ... ) and measure how fit and well-shape I am?

```
I can calculate:
BMI, WHR, FAT composition, bone type, calorie need. by myself but I don't know how to relate them to my fitness
```

if any know such a resource or know how to measure by myself please tell.

any answer appreciate.

Comment: There *are* standardized tests like the Functional Movement Screen.

Comment: related: [How can I measure my fitness at home without any instruments?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/how-can-i-measure-my-fitness-at-home-without-any-instruments?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single scale on which we all can measure and compare our fitness levels.

For starters, there are a thousand different ways of being in shape. You can be a great sprinter or marathon runner, swimmer, boxer, kickboxer, rock climber, tree climber, mountain climber, indoor climber, weightlifter, powerlifter, olympic lifter, and the list goes on and on and on, for every sport you can imagine.

And the point here is that the people who excel at these activities, are all in tremendously good shape, but in completely different ways. The olympic lifter can swing huge weights over his head, but can't run more than a few miles without stopping/walking. Meanwhile, the marathon runner can run miles and miles without pause, but can barely benchpress his bodyweight.

These are obviously just examples with moderation, but still pretty literal.

If we were to have one single test to measure one's fitness level, we'd have to test all these attributes, which isn't a realistic option.

If we did have such a scale and test, we could all take the test, and literally find the most in-shape person on the planet. He or she would be pretty damn good at every single sport and activity. On the flip side, we'd also find the *least* in-shape person on the planet...

EDIT: Based on your comment, and my superior hindsight, it sounds like you're looking for the ol' army fitness test, whereby you're tested on a short run, as well as a few bodyweight exercises. In this case, there again is no *one* standard, as different workplaces look for different qualities. So for instance the army might place more focus on cardiovascular qualities, while a fire brigade might emphasize strength.

By googling "physical fitness test" you'll find a few alternatives, made by different institutions. One of the top results should be the US Army PFT, which is likely the most used one.

But again, I warn you; this does not test **all** aspects of your fitness. Such a test would be far more compounded.

Comment: Hey. U know I mean a person is going to get in shape and gain a fitness. And ofcource it is globally the same in all kinda people... I mean some tests lile pushup which measure strength. Or seat and reach which measure flexibility. A fixed workouts and tests which measure all aspects of my fitness.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks for spending time.. really really thank you

Comment: Wrong.  Strength norms, VO2, Life expectancy, body fat,   National Academy of Sciences,  Institute of Medicine, National Institutes of Health, ACSM,  and on and on.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous tests in existence, have a read of: [101 Evaluation Tests](http://www.pponline.co.uk/101Evaluations/pdfs/101EvaluationTests.Chapter.1.pdf), as to an App / Website again there are numerous, even the likes of [Polar Beat](http://www.polar.com/en/about_polar/press_room/press_releases/popular_polar_beat_app_now_tests_athletes_fitness), [Endomondo](http://blog.endomondo.com/2013/04/17/test-your-fitness-level-with-the-new-android-app-8-7-0-2/), [BioMetrIcs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.arcalot.biometrics).... all offer a few of the more common tests.

Just don't ask as to which test is [best](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24250/fitness-tests-is-there-a-consensus-on-which-to-use)?

Answer (score 0):

I can share only what I experienced by myself. Fitbit Aria weights + Fitbit Charge HR.

Since I bought weights I drop 6kg, since having wristband I started walk 20K steps a day. All in one complete solution helps you to track activity in one place.