# Fitness asssesment for boulderers?

Tags: body-measurements, measurements, assesment

This [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/fitness-assessments) is a general question about fitness but it does not address the important features of boulderers such as strength of skin, strength of finger/arm/hand muscles and determination/discipline. The last one is a bit ambiguous but by that I am trying to measure the level of determination: perhaps some path tests with some traps.

**How can the boulderers assess their fitness level?**

[image]

Comment: "determination" is not a fitness measurement; skin strength is not something that is easily measurable and as far as hand/finger/arm strength is concerned, the same way you measure strength everywhere: being able to perform a certain feat for a given number of reps/time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Jamar hand dynamometer can be used to measure grip strength and I believe was used last year during the selection of the British bouldering team.