# why am i suddently so worn out in cardio?

Tags: weight-loss, cardio, resistancetraining, lifting

I started gym 2 months ago and nearly every day except maybe 1 one rest day I will complete 1 hour cardio (about 500 calories, some days even 600-700) and an hour intense weight training targeting all major muscle groups (leg Monday, abs Tuesday etc).
However lately (past 2 weeks) I burn about 80 and I am WORN out and over it and no energy (however push through it and just have more breaks & rests until I can atleast reach 300)
What could be some causes for this?
I weigh 145 pounds, 170 tall.
Am female & eat around 1500 cals.
Take a pre workout fat burner everyday and post workout whey protein.
This still happens even if I go not fasted & eat before.
Happens even after rest day and adequate sleep.
Could this be because of eating a calorie restriction for so long whilst straining my body?
My calorie defecit is only 500 less than what it should be to try and lose weight.
Any suggestions or advice?
and no I don't over train my muscles and get adequate sleep

Comment: 1 rest day per what? You're at a good weight for a 170cm woman so maybe your calorie deficit at your workload is not helping you. Hard to say what to do without knowing your current program and what your goals are.

Comment: Agreed with @Megasaur. You are doing too much and not resting/eating enough. I have explained this in your previous question http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18320/why-is-the-weight-not-falling-off-me

Comment: How did this start? Did you have one day where you felt very poor, and then things didn't improve? Or has it been a gradual drop? Also, do you feel hungry, or do you usually feel as though the 1500 is enough?