# What is the "kernel" for a 4 decade training program for physical fitness?

Tags: weightlifting, cardio, workout-routines, training, tracking

Almost all training programs or workout routines are focused on the very short term, e.g. 90 days, 12 weeks and similar.

My questions is about the "kernel" (key elements in a wide sense) for a training program that can work throughout at least half of an expected life time for most people in the developed world. A long term training program that manages the changes in care taking situations (children, ageing parents), injuries (permanent, temporary, ..), physical capability, income, moving to different countries/regions and work situations.

On Google Scholar, it seems like the topic "lifelong physical training" generates interesting results, see ["life long physical training"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=lifelong%20physical%20training). Habits seems to be important for people to maintain long training programs. See for example, "Physical activity and muscle training in the elderly." a 20 year study on male "orienterare". However, I know many in that sport that have changed to other sports or - in most cases - stopped training.

On the commercial side, there are a number of gyms in the US that promises "life long fitness" but their methods seem to be the same as other gyms

Comment: Hi @Fredob, questions that are so broad generally have no one real answer. Is there any specific problem your facing? Like picking a type of sports you can remain active in for decades? The whole point there are dozens of different types of sports is because everybody has different needs and preferences. So I'd advise you to change the focus of your question, else we'll probably has to close it for being too broad.

Comment: The problem with your question is that goals change over the course of time.  When goals are reached, we replace them with new goals--or get bored and quit.  Most programs are centered around achieving a specific goal.  So the question is this: what do you see yourself doing over 40 years?  If you can answer that, we can give some advice on what should remain a core component of your training.  As it is, your answers would be equally as broad as your question.

Comment: On a 40-year time frame, I don't think we're going to be able to get any more specific than "stay active". Maybe "keep strength, mobility, and conditioning in mind"?

Comment: I've been in sports for 41 years (First swim meet when I was 4), so I could give you n=1 experience, but as it is, your question is way to wide spanning.

Comment: @IvoFlipse, perhaps I can precise a bit more what I mean by a "kernel" (like the ones you have in operating systems, concept in SEMAT, and in strategy). I think the answer from Robin points in the direction of what kind of training that is sustainable for a long period. I.e. should have the highest priority.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, I do agree that goals change over time. However, when you get into the "get bored and quit" or "can't perform as I did when {at peak, when young, ..}, I have seen many people just quit all training. Perhaps I should add more of this reasoning in the question?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing that answering this question would help you with?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann, agree that "stay active" is the (too) general formula but I think that part of the kernel should be to monitor your capability (strenght, mobility and conditioning)

Comment: @fredob i believe "kernels" should broken up into aerobic output activities such as swimming, running, biking and anaerobic activities in weightlifting which consist of the core lifts (press, squats and deads).  Put that into a program and you'll always be fit.

Comment: @JohnP, increasing n to a higher number would be interesting. Perhaps a part of the "kernel" would be to be actively share experiences.

Comment: @Sancho, I think the problem that I am facing is to have a framework for executing various training programs over time.

Comment: @Andreas, good point. However, I am not sure whether anaerobic and aerobic are the best categories. In my own experiments, I see that I get a high training effect when I do weight-lifting (e.g. measured as high pulse over time).

Comment: @fredob lol actually i totally agree.  I get a much higher training effect as well from weightlifting.  I just wanted to state what most generic books display as "kernels".

Comment: I gave a 'real' answer and comment below so I may be entitled to an off point comment now. It seems that nothing much has really changed since gladiators trained with clapperless bells (dumbbells comes from a Roman essay). Won't we have an implanted computer controlled micro-pump for safe drugs that solve all our fitness problems within 20 years?  What effect will that have on our lives? I can't imagine my life being better without the gym. I gave your question another point. It was even better than I first realized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, as fredob requested, this is an n=1 style of writeup, for my experiences and what I consider to be the core kernels of a lifetime fitness program. Note, this is not a design for specific competition, this is fitness in general. Obviously if you compete, you would need to tweak the physical component and nutrition components to support that.

**NUTRITION**

This is the first component, and arguably the most important. You can be running 75 miles a week, throwing around heavy weights, whatever your activity might be, but shoveling big macs and fries down 4 days a week with pizza and ice cream chasers. If you don't supply your body in a healthy way, you can't expect it to perform consistently. Note I say nutrition, and not diet. In my mind, diet implies a process. The problem with a process is that it has a beginning, and an end. There is no end. You either have good nutrition planning or you don't. Doesn't mean that you can't have cheat days, fall of the wagon a bit, etc., but overall your nutrition plan is sound and based in your needs for daily existence plus your activity.

**MENTAL ACTIVITY**

This is the second component. Protect your mind. Play games, play an instrument, read a book, do puzzles, whatever floats your boat. Keeping your mind active and well rounded will enable you to still be sharp and on top of things well into your twilight years. The more active you can be, the better.

**PHYSICAL ACTIVITY**

Get out. Do SOMETHING. Walk, ride a bike, swim, play horseshoes, move around, anything. Get your heart rate up, sweat a little, make your body work. Find something you truly enjoy doing, because like a diet, "getting in shape" or doing something you don't like for the sake of activity is a dead end process. Ok, so you got in shape. Now what? But, if you truly enjoy what you're doing, you'll keep on doing it.

**RESISTANCE TRAINING**

More and more, studies are showing that resistance training can help preserve muscle as we age. Take a look at what you do in your physical activity, and plan your resistance training to supplement that, and keep your muscles in balance. A lot of back problems, for instance, could be alleviated if people trained their spinal muscles as much as their trophy abs. You don't necessarily have to heave around small cars, but especially as you age, resistance training can help preserve muscle.

**BALANCE**

Keep your life in balance. Make time for your sports, family, work, personal time, etc. When you start sacrificing one for the other, your life eventually starts spinning out of control. There will be times when you HAVE to sacrifice for a bit, but let those be as short as possible.

Now, I have been in sports for 41 years. This includes 17 years swimming, 9 years cross country (HS/College), 2 years wrestling, 4 years competitive cycling, almost 20 years in martial arts. I've competed at every level from local clubs to a handful of Nationals and a couple of Worlds. As soon as something stops being fun, I find something else. (I walked out on two years of scholarship in swimming because I was burned out. Still hate swimming.) I play D&D, board games, poker, chess. I have an outstanding wife and wonderful family. I recognize my capabilities, and I'm still not sure if I've found my limits or not.

In those 41 years, I've had one injury (Ruptured achilles 6 weeks ago) that kept me sidelined for more than a week. I attribute this to a lifetime of athletics, lucky genetics, and enough sense to monitor myself and sensibly push my limits, and staying within the above categories.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: How important is a "training log"? I found one question about this, see http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/3300/3778

Comment: @fredob - Training logs are self dependent. Some people like them, others (like myself) struggle to maintain it on a consistent basis. I have found that when I managed to keep a consistent log, I could look at it and figure out why I wasn't feeling good in a workout, or that I was getting stale, etc. It also helps you to keep track, instead of thinking "Ok, so I did lats Wed...or Thu...wait..." In short, I am FOR training logs, I just personally have a really hard time maintaining them day to day.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the book "Practical Programming for Strength Training" by Rippetoe and Kilgore. It is aimed at the college educated professional strength coach and covers every aspect of developing training programs. While overly detailed for the likes of us, it is the basis for lifetime learning. BTW I'm over 60 and started lifting in my teens. I've always put my education, career, and personal relationships first so I've taken many lay-offs - some of them long. The key attitude is *wanting* to lift when you have time/energy as opposed to feeling you *had better* start lifting now.

Comment: Will check out the work by Rippletoe (have looked at the vidoes). Your own practical experiences are interesting, especially the prioritization and the motivational part. Over the decades, how have you tracked your training?

Comment: "Back in the day" we just kept fairly free form notebooks and then over time lost the books and/or just stopped keeping them having become know-it-alls. Now I'm a beginner again in that I'm in a new world of aches, strains, and injuries so I'm back to notebooks. New for me is a food diary with protein and calorie counts. I'm non-digital only because I've been a computer scientist forever. I found a notebook page from 1987 - I'm back to my best trained weight (joy!). I wish I had kept more.

Answer (score 4):

Lifting heavy weights. Everything else you might do depends on strength, so if you don't have that, you'll be limited. If you do have it, everything will improve for you. You'll be more flexible, have better endurance, will be less injury prone and will recover from injuries faster.

It's also very sustainable. You can do one short, high intensity lifting routine per week, not have any significant (or any at all) soreness the following days and make gains (or, once you start hitting the peak of your potential, sustain them). 5 minutes, to do one set of squats or deadlifts, one set of presses and one set of pull ups with sufficient weight to keep you under 10 reps will keep you going, and it's something you'll be able to fit in, even with a changing schedule. Not included in the one set is doing 1-2 warmup sets of 5 reps with lower weights. The best thing is, within a half an hour cooldown after the set you'll still be in shape to do any physical activity that's necessary for your life, and you won't have worn out your muscles that you couldn't move furniture for the next two days.

Obviously there will be some scenarios in which a weight room just isn't available, but there really isn't anything else that could make up the core of your program that can adjust to the changes in life. There's bodyweight routines and rope skipping, but those end up taking a lot more time, which makes them a lot harder to sustain over weeks or months (unless you're doing handstand pushups).

The other answer is walking. 30 minutes per day (or at least 3x/week). That has been shown repeatedly to significantly reduce the risk of most illnesses, compared to being completely sedentary. I have a hard time calling that a fitness routine though, it's really more of a bare minimum. I can't really think of a scenario in which 30 minutes of walking isn't possible.

Comment: So a key element would be lifting heavy weight in a "maintenance state" as you described about once a week. Another would be to be "every day active". I know I have read that you also should be active at least every 40-45 minutes, will check up that reference

Comment: http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/01/12/the-hazards-of-the-couch/ A summary is that if you are too inactive (i.e. more than four hours) then doing high intensity doesn't help you.

Comment: I'm sorry--5 minutes to do squats or deadlifts, a set of presses, and a set of pull-ups, once per week, and this will create gains to the peak of your potential? I think this needs a rewording or clarification. Most people need 5 minutes just to get warm to prevent injury, and one set each, once a week (while probably not so bad for health purposes) can't be said to get you anywhere close to your potential.

Comment: Mike Mentzer has made exactly that claim, and he's certainly someone who got to the peak of his potential. So unless he's practicing something entirely different from what he preaches, it's not an unreasonable position. Note though, that I made no claims myself about it being sufficient to reach your peak potential, so I'm not sure what rewording or clarification is necessary.

Comment: Mike Mentzer, Bill Pearl, Vince Gironda,... I've read them all - of course the publisher's blurbs stress the differences, not what they agree on. They write for an audience that spends too much time in the gym talking and then doing too many exercises for too few muscles using ineffective form with pointless weight. Training to true failure requires experienced spotters. Training to technical failure requires experience and humility. Stopping just before that last possible good rep might be best, but...Then of course there is the issue of the perfect warm up. Oh, and of course steroids.

Comment: @robin ashe, I was ready to give you a high five until I saw the five minutes item. While your scenario is better than doing nothing (as long as the weight is low enough to avoid injury) I think it will not stimulate muscle growth. A light weighted warmup followed by 2-3 sets, with significant (3-5 min) rest between sets will give better results.

Comment: I don't even have to wait for you to try to answer to know that you'll be unable to find an proof for your assertion that you need multiple sets with at least 3 minutes of rest in between to see optimum results.

Comment: @J.WinchesterI think that if you are in a "maintenance state" the the idea of doing one set fits the overall picture better (less time etc) My own experience is that the negative thoughts of not being able to do the best workout stops you from working out at all.

Comment: @robinashe I bet you are correct that there is no proof for optimality three sets vs one or five... However there is proof that you will not get maximum exertion when not warmed up. Someone who goes to a barbell (assuming somebody has already set up 3 different barbells with plates pre-loaded for all three exercises?) bangs out 20-30 total reps of three dif

Comment: @J.Winchester good point, I realise I forgot to mention doing warmup sets.

Comment: comment got garbled; anyways you get the point. +1