# How to plan exercise for the day?

Tags: exercise, workout-routines

I do exercise daily but I don't have a plan. I use to do some push ups, crunches, etc few months ago. Nowadays I go for walking but that too not daily. I would like to plan my exercise but I really don't know how to do so. Could you help me out?

Comment: Based on your question, it seems like your goal is more like "general stay healthy" than a specific event or lose weight. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a **plan** because you ***don't*** have a **goal**. Set a goal, and then create a plan to reach that goal.

For me (Goal)
I want to go from 93kg's to 70kg's.

Plan

- Jog every day for 5km adding 5% distance every week
- Calorie intake of 1200 (10% fat, 30% protein, 60% carbs)

Result
Weight is currently 85Kg's and 15kg's to go.

Comment: Excellent point making it goal oriented. +1

Comment: Just a update on this original post. I'm now 65kg's and been stable for the past 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

For "general stay healthy" plans (not to reduce weight or practice for an event), my suggestion is that you first set up goals in terms of **time** for these three categories:

- Moderate physical activity (MPA)
- High Intensity physical activity (HPA)
- Recovery activities (RA)

MPA is activities where your [perceived effort](http://fcesoftware.com/images/15_Perceived_Exertion.pdf) is low, i.e. on a scale of 1 to 10, your effort is at most 4 to 5. Typical activities are walking, biking, slow swimming and hiking.

HPA is activities where you effort is higher that 6. E.g. [tabata](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabata), fast swimming and [crossfit](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossfit).

RA is activities where your effort is 1-2. E.g. Yoga, social activities and household chores.

The goals in time per week for a minimal "general stay healthy" base load should be:

- MPA: [150, 210] minutes, see this [reference](http://www.cdc.gov/physicalactivity/everyone/guidelines/adults.html).
- HPA: [15, 25] minutes, see this [article](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/06/19/the-4-minute-workout/?_r=0) in NY Times (that refers
  to research done in Norway).
- RA: [60, 300] minutes, depending on overall level of stress at
  work/school, see this [reference](http://kops.ub.uni-konstanz.de/bitstream/handle/urn:nbn:de:bsz:352-opus-56948/sonnentag_JOHP_2001.pdf?sequence=1).

The advantage of time as a basis for the goals is that you can vary the exercises and thus reduce the risk of injuries.

The general "stay healthy" is a life long project, see this [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7258/3778). To make is more manageable my experience is to plan forward 3-4 months at the time. That is, track what you do for the next three months, see if you can exceed stay in the suggested ranges for the goals and at the end of the period evaluate and adjust.